# How to prevent some fields of my object to be transformed by class-transformer

Tags: json, typescript, firebase, class-transformer

I'm trying to use the library `class-transformer`(https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) to serialize typescript classes to firebase, which doesn't accept customs types.

The thing is some of the data are actually data compatible with firebase, like "coordinates" being in the GeoPoint format.

I've this class being serialized:

```
export abstract class StopStep extends Step {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  pointOfInterest: PointOfInterest | null;
  address: string;
  coordinates: firebase.firestore.GeoPoint;
}
```

I would like to prevent the "coordinates" field to be transformed. It should be present, just not untransformed.

I tried to play with the `@Transform(({value})=>...)`, but it appears it's only an "additional" transformation, it doesn't allow me to just keep the same format.

I also tried `Exclude`, but then the field isn't present anymore.

Is there a way to accomplish this with this library?

Comment: same situation here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Answer:** I've analyzed and debugged the whole [TransformOperationExecutor.ts](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/develop/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts), and simply put, there is no in-build way to suppress the myriad of transformations this executor attempts to do. I thought maybe removing the `@Type` decorator all together could achieve the goal. But even with the missing type information, the library still tries to transform complex objects into plain objects as best as possible. The reason why `@Transform(({value})=>...)` is not working is that even for the returned value, there are multiple checks to figure out if the transformed value needs any further transformations to be "*plain*".

**Workaround:**
The only solution I see is to build that functionality yourself. I can offer the following  implementation to simulate an `@Ignore` feature:

```js
import { classToPlain, ClassTransformOptions, Transform, TransformFnParams } from 'class-transformer';

// New decorator to be used on members that should not be transformed.
export function Ignore() {
    // reuse transform decorator
    return Transform((params: TransformFnParams) => {
        if (params.type == TransformationType.CLASS_TO_PLAIN) {
            // class-transformer won't touch functions,
            // so we use function-objects as container to skip transformation.
            const container = () => params.value;
            container.type = '__skipTransformContainer__';

            return container;
        }
        // On other transformations just return the value.
        return params.value;
    });
}

// Extended classToPlain to unwrap the container objects
export function customClassToPlain<T>(object: T, options?: ClassTransformOptions) {
    const result = classToPlain(object, options);
    unwrapSkipTransformContainers(result);
    return result;
}

// Recursive function to iterate over all keys of an object and its nested objects.
function unwrapSkipTransformContainers(obj: any) {
    for (const i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            const currentValue = obj[i];
            if (currentValue?.type === '__skipTransformContainer__') {
                // retrieve the original value and also set it.
                obj[i] = currentValue();
                continue;
            }

            // recursion + recursion anchor
            if (typeof currentValue === 'object') {
                unwrapSkipTransformContainers(currentValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution exploits that the class-transformer won't transform functions (except get/set functions), as those are not part of a plain object. We reuse the `Transform` decorator to wrap members we don't want to be transformed with a function. We also mark those functions with the string `__skipTransformContainer__` to make it easy to find them later and not accidentally call the wrong functions. Then we write a new `customClassToPlain`, which first calls the default `classToPlain` and then calls a recursive unwrap function on the result. The unwrap function is called `unwrapSkipTransformContainer` and recursively searches all `__skipTransformContainer__`-containers to retrieve the untransformed values.

**Usage:**

```js
export abstract class StopStep extends Step {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  pointOfInterest: PointOfInterest | null;
  address: string;
  @Ignore()
  coordinates: firebase.firestore.GeoPoint;
}

class ExampleStep extends StopStep {/*logic*/}
    
const step = new ExampleStep();
const plain = customClassToPlain(step);
```

Comment: A little side note i've noticed: The classToPlain type declarion of "class-transformer" is bugged. classToPlain([obj1, obj2]) is returning the type Record<string, any>, but should return Record<string, any>[].

Comment: Thank you for all your work, seems great! I've to test this tomorrow. I guess I also would have to do some custom method to convert back(plain to typescript) ? If this work, do you think a pull request should be done to the repo?

Comment: A feature request would be fine, but not a pull request. It would be way easier to implement if you could alter TransformOperationExecutor. They just had to add an additional else branch and store some metadata.

Comment: Made an update to the code to also support plain to class. The other way around its easier and you don't need a custom method.

Comment: @J4N could you already test if it's working for you?

Comment: I've, it seems to be working fine! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Bad news;** Micro S. is right. "class-transformer" forces to apply default transformation even you have a custom transformation function. This limits usage of custom transformation function, and means "you can not return what ever you want".

**Good news;** JavaScript is a high flexible language. This means you can override any function of a class prototype. The code below fixes this issue without loosing performance.

```
import isPlainObject from 'putil-isplainobject';

const oldTransformFn = TransformOperationExecutor.prototype.transform;
TransformOperationExecutor.prototype.transform =
  function transform(source: Record<string, any> | Record<string, any>[] | any,
                     value: Record<string, any> | Record<string, any>[] | any,
                     targetType: Function | TypeMetadata,
                     // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
                     arrayType: Function,
                     // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
                     isMap: boolean,
                     // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
                     level?: number): any {
    // @ts-ignore
    if (isPlainObject(value) && targetType === Object) {
      return value;
    }
    // @ts-ignore
    return oldTransformFn.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```